# sorted in desending order using mongoRepository

Tags: spring-boot, mongorepository

I am a beginner on spring boot and mongodb I want to use @query to display the files in descending order can you give me an idea?

```
public class file{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime datecreated;
    
    // constructor, getters, setters  
}

public interface FileRepository extends MongoRepository<file, String> {
    
  // @Query("{}")
   List<file> findByname(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing custom queries in your repository layer, you can sort on invocation. You can follow an approach as below.

***Repository***:

```
@Query("{...}")
List<file> findByname(String name, Sort sort);
```

***Sort on invocation***:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "sorting field");
List<file> data = repository.findByname(name, sort);
```

**There can be multiple ways to do this. This is just one of them.**

Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 3):

for `@Query` annotation:
1 = ASC, -1 = DESC

```java
@Query(sort="{'name':-1}")
List<file> findByName(String name);
```

Comment: please if I want to sort first by date and second by name, I am looking for the syntax, for example @Query(sort="{'name':-1},{'dateCreated':-1}"), how i Can Do this ?

Comment: try `Query(sort="{'name':-1 , 'dateCreated':-1}")` this

Comment: use reverse order of above